# kendo chart change individual markers type on the same series

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is there a way to assign different markers types (circle, square, triangle, etc) to specific data points on the same series? (I am using scatterLine chart)

I know it can be done with the color:
[Assigning specific color to each data point example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxoLO/18)

And also you can change the type for the whole series: [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxoLO)

But I need to have on the same line at least 2 different types (circles and triangles)

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.markers.visual)** of the series markers to draw the shape you want e.g.:

```
series: [{
  type: "line",
  markers: {
    visual: function (e) {
      var origin = e.rect.origin;
      var center = e.rect.center();
      var bottomRight = e.rect.bottomRight();

      if (e.value < 2){
        return e.createVisual();
      } else {
        var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
          stroke: {color: e.options.border.color, width: 2},
          fill: { color: "white" }
        })
        .moveTo(origin.x, bottomRight.y)
        .lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
        .lineTo(center.x, origin.y)
        .close();

        return path;
      }
    }
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/oZUNoJ)**

Comment: Thanks a lot that should make it. I saw an example with images, didn't know shapes can be created.
By any chance do you have more shapes options examples other than the triangle (like the ones provided by default 'square', 'cross') , I would really appreciated it.. if not that's ok I'll figure it out

Comment: @Coto, i don't have shapes off hand, you have to draw them. Square should be easy: move to top corner and lineTo each corner. Cross you could draw two lines, etc.